# Need to get year and Month based on number of days

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to get the Validity in years and months or only months if less than 365  of a Package based on the number of days stored in database.

What I did was stored the validity count of a package in days. eg. 1680 or 365.

I need to display 5 years and 1 years x month respectively.

I have been calculating 1 month as 28 days.

Can someone help me? What I tried:

```
if (days_count > 336) { 
    year = count/28*12; // here i will get the year.how will i get Month 
} else {
    // calculate for month and days
    month = count/28;
}
```

Comment: php or Javascript?

Comment: Please clarify whether the solution should be in javascript, php or both.

Comment: FYI, not all years have 365 days…

Comment: It seems more of a 'math' query then the programming one because you already are getting 'year', why cant you get month?

Comment: Php or javascri[t will be just fine ...@briosheje

Comment: Yes Exactly , it has to do with math ...@Karan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$count = 1710;
$totalMonth =  (int) ($count/28) ; // 5
echo $year =  (int) ($totalMonth/12);// 1
echo $month =  $totalMonth % 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question which is commented on your code, you should use a combination of mod operator and / operator to get month number.

```
year = count / (28 * 12);
month = (count % (28 *12)) / 28;
```

this should give you correct year and month count however using 28 as the sum of days in month seems a little bit strange.
Also make sure you use parantheses around 28 *12 otherwise your compiler ot interpreter mixes up priority of operations.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, this is what you are looking for:

```js
function convertNumberOfDaysToMonthYear(numberOfDays) {
  var str = '';

  var values = [
    [' year', 365],
    [' month', 28],
    [' day', 1]
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var amount = Math.floor(numberOfDays / values[i][1]);
    if (amount >= 1) {
      str += amount + values[i][0] + (amount > 1 ? 's' : '') + ' ';
      numberOfDays -= amount * values[i][1];
    }
  }

  return str;
}

console.log(convertNumberOfDaysToMonthYear(367));
console.log(convertNumberOfDaysToMonthYear(730));
console.log(convertNumberOfDaysToMonthYear(1000));
```

Comment: This is exactly what i  was loocking for Thanks alot .